# Где выводить сообщение об исключении? try-catch

Tags: c++, исключения

Допустим, вызывается функция, в которой вызывается еще 2 других функции, в которых вызываются еще несколько других функций. Где выводить сообщение об исключении? Каждую функцию обернуть в `try-catch` и локально выводить ошибку? Или каждую функцию обернуть в `try-catch`, а в `catch` бросать (`throw`) исключение дальше, до самой первой функции? Или большой разницы нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там, где вы уже не в состоянии обработать исключение иначе как вывести сообщение.

Если функция не в состоянии обработать исключение, лучше ей передать его вверх, вызывающей функции: возможно, она сумеет разобраться с ним лучше. Ну, а в `main`, если ничего иного не остается, то...

Например, функция должна открыть файл, которого нет, и при этом сгенерировано исключение. Выводить сообщение? А если эта функция всего лишь часть алгоритма, который работает с пользовательским вводом, и пользователь просто ошибся, и может ввести новое имя файла, если ему это предложить?

Словом, нет конкретных советов - делай так, и не иначе. Обычное правило - перехватывает тот, кто знает, как обработать исключение.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*